# don't slide left if it is beginning of the DIV using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to disable a button that is used to slide left a DIV using jquery if it is the beginning of the DIV.

basically everything works fine as they should but the issue is that if the user clicks on the left slide button at the beginning of the div, it will slide left into an empty space!

This is my current code:

```
<script>
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
$( ".block" ).animate({ "margin-left": "-=580px" }, "slow" );
});
$( "#left" ).click(function(){
$( ".block" ).animate({ "margin-left": "+=580px" }, "slow" );
});

</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="slideshow" style="padding-left:15px; overflow:hidden; ">

<div class="block" id="slider" style="width:500000px; ">



Big Content goes here..............................................


</div>


</div>
```

is there anyway to stop the div to go left if it reaches the beginning of the div `id="slider"`?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

edit my entire HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>




<div id="slideshow" style="padding-left:15px; overflow:hidden; width:770px; border:solid 2px #000;">

<div class="block" id="slider" style="width:500000px; ">



long content ..................................................................................................................


</div>
</div> 


<button class="triggerSlide" style="border: none; background: url('arleft.png') no-repeat; width:39px; height:39px; cursor:pointer;" id="left">&laquo;

</button>
<button class="triggerSlide" style="border: none; background: url('arright.png') no-repeat; width:39px; height:39px; cursor:pointer;"  id="right">&raquo;</button>    


<script>
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
    if( !$(".block").is(':animated') ) {
        var slideStep = 580;
        var marg = $( ".block" ).css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
        var newMargin = parseInt(marg, 10) - parseInt(slideStep, 10);
        var maxMarg = $( ".block" ).css('width').replace('px', '');
       var winWidth = $("#slideshow").width()

        if(Math.abs(newMargin) <= maxMarg && (newMargin <= winWidth)) {
            $( ".block" ).animate({ "margin-left": "-=" + slideStep + "px" }, "slow" );
        }
    }
});

$( "#left" ).click(function(){
    if( !$(".block").is(':animated') ) {
        var slideStep = 580;
        var marg = $( ".block" ).css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
        var newMargin = parseInt(marg, 10) + parseInt(slideStep, 10);
        var maxMarg = $( ".block" ).css('width').replace('px', '');
        var winWidth = $("#slideshow").width()

        if(Math.abs(newMargin) <= maxMarg && (newMargin <= winWidth)) {
            $( ".block" ).animate({ "margin-left": "+=" + slideStep + "px" }, "slow" );
        }
    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle for the same?

Comment: provide fiddle and also try to explain your problem some more

Comment: Use offset() to calculate how much your .block has moved. If it is zero or less it shouldn't add margin-left.

Comment: @trainoasis, any chance of an example of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not very helpful, but anyway. You can try checking [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) or [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) of your element before moving it further. (depending on what you need exactly)

You can add this just before moving your .block element to the left

```
var offset = $( ".block" ).offset(); 
var leftOffset = offset.left;
```

Now you can check what that leftOffset is each time you move your element.

Now it shouldn't be hard for you to figure out when to move and when not to move your block based on this value, right? :) (a little math will do you good)

If you need more help let me know

**EDIT**

You can try something like this inside your click event for left:

```
var offset = $( ".block" ).offset(); 
var leftOffset = offset.left;

if(leftOffset<580)
    $( ".block" ).animate({ "margin-left": "+=580px" }, "slow" );
```

Comment: thats the thing, all that math looks daunting. I'm not a jquery wiz by any means.

Comment: this makes the left slide button to stop working! i can only slide right.

Comment: in your test, when you click on the slide left button, it goes to an empty space even though it is at the beginning of the Div.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: basically, your code does exactly what my own code does. no difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58358/discussion-between-trainoasis-and-user3806613).

Comment: And what if the window/parent width is less than 580px? You will also lose the scrolled item!

Comment: Easy to fix with calculating that value dynamically

Comment: Yes. Easy also to handle the too quick double click where in your case the scroll is moving outside (=> bug). It's all handled in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Working sample (see fiddle under).
I used the marginLeft property and compare it to the parent width & div width to limit the move to let it visible.

Right now with this code:

- If the content is already moving (case when you double click on the button), we don't launch another move to avoid getting out of the screen
- If you got a bigger/smaller screen or div size, no problem
- If you scroll till the end of the div, the last scroll will be adapted to still display all the div to the end (with the parent padding if existing)

Code:

```
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
    if( !$(".block").is(':animated') ) {
        var slideStep = 280;
        var marg = $( ".block" ).css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
        var newMargin = parseInt(marg, 10) - parseInt(slideStep, 10);
        var maxMarg = $( ".block" ).width() + 12;
        var winWidth = $("#slideshow").width();

        if(Math.abs(newMargin) <= maxMarg && (newMargin <= winWidth)) {
            slideStep = Math.min(slideStep, parseInt(maxMarg, 10) - Math.abs(marg) - parseInt(winWidth, 10));
            $( ".block" ).animate({ "margin-left": "-=" + slideStep + "px" }, "slow" );
        }
    }
});

$( "#left" ).click(function(){
    if( !$(".block").is(':animated') ) {
        var slideStep = 280;
        var marg = $( ".block" ).css('marginLeft').replace('px', '');
        var newMargin = parseInt(marg, 10) + parseInt(slideStep, 10);
        var maxMarg = $( ".block" ).width() + 12;
        var winWidth = $("#slideshow").width();

        if(Math.abs(newMargin) <= maxMarg && (newMargin <= winWidth)) {
            slideStep = Math.min(slideStep, Math.abs(marg));
            $( ".block" ).animate({ "margin-left": "+=" + slideStep + "px" }, "slow" );
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nrobert/VD58b/7/

Added `animated` check to avoid sliding too much when clicking several times quickly on the buttons.
Now checking width against parent, not window, and adapted slide value to avoid big white spaces at the beginning or end

Comment: This doesn't work for me as it checks it against the window width! how about if I have the div's centered in the page and the container div has marging left/top/right values? that is my case by the way.

Comment: If you want to stop the slide when the item is outside the window (that is to say: stop sliding to avoid sliding to an empty space) you have to use something. As the structure you gave us has only 2 divs, I used the window.

If we do not have all the info about your configuration, you will not have a perfect answer! You can customize the answer by changing window.width by the parent you need...

Comment: Yes you are correct. sorry my bad. I'm not a jquery wiz so i don't know how things are done to start with.

Comment: That's absolutely not a jquery problematic here, only html/css.
If you want more info, update your question with all your page structure (html), the css linked to this page, etc.

Comment: am I in the correct path if I do this `var winWidth = $( "#slideshow" ).css('width');` ?

Comment: you can directly call `var winWidth = $("#slideshow").width()`.
From jquery documentation: The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px)

Comment: still goes/slides to the left to an empty space, even though it is at the beginning of div.

Comment: there is still a little space (not fully white) in the fiddle at the extrem, are you talking about that? Or are you talking about your local tests that we cannot see and understand?

Comment: i've added my entire HTML code. as you can see, the left slide button, makes the div to go to the left at the beginning of the div. i hope that makes sense now. PS, I was referring to my own code.